# Is variable updated "by reference"?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following simple script.

```
<script>
SPC = {
    a : [10],
    b : 10,

    t: function()
    {
        y = this.a;
        z = this.b;
        y[0]++;
        z++;
        alert('this.a[0] = ' + this.a[0] + '\nthis.b = ' + this.b)
    }
}

SPC.t();
SPC.t();
</script>
```

Running it in your browser will display two alert boxes with:

this.a[0] = 11
this.b = 10

and

this.a[0] = 12
this.b = 10

The question is, why does the value of this.a[0] increment? I'm assigning "y = this.a" and updating element of "y" as "y[0]++;"?

At the same time, exactly the same thing is happening with "b": "z = this.b; z++". Yet, "this.b" remains equal to 10.

How can I change value of "y[0]" in the local scope without affecting "this.a"?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` is an array, and you're simply copying a reference to the array into `y`. You need to copy the array `a`'s *contents* into a *new array* `y` instead (using `Array.slice()` (`y = a.slice()` in your case) is the easiest way).

(Or, if you only need `a[0]`, you can set `y = a[0]`. Subsequent changes to `y` will not affect `a[0]`, since you are copying the value.)

See the "Javascript Arrays Are Assigned By Reference" and "Passing Arrays As Values" sections of [this article](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function.

```
y = this.a.slice()
```

This will create a copy of `a` array and assign it to `y`. So modification of `y` won't affect `a`.

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning the address value of array a and b into y and z.
therefore, y, and z become the exact copy of a and b.
instead of assigning address value into y and z.
you just need to take content value of a and b and assign them into y and z
y = a[0]

z = b[0]

and then y++